# Split a list after a character and find errors on that line if existent

Tags: python, string, list

I have this code:

```
import re
accents = ['é', 'à', 'è', 'ù', 'â', 'ê', 'î', 'ô', 'û', 'ç', 'ë', 'ï', 'ü']


with open("test.txt", 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
        #print(line)
    for line in lines:
        for accent in accents:
            if accent in line:
                my_list = line.split(accent)
                #print(my_list)
                for x in my_list:
                    if x[-1] == "(" or x[0] == "|" or x[-1] == "|" or x[0] == ")":
                        pass
                    else:
                        print(
                            "Error found on line:",
                            lines.index(line)+1,
                            ",", f'"{accent}"',
                            "has no accent variation")
                        my_list.pop(1)
```

And this is the content of the *test.txt* file:

```
t(é|e)làphone|télephone|portland(e|é)
```

I split the text every time I find an accent that was used, in this way I can look before and after the split to make sure I have a round bracket or pipeline.
My aim is to find all the accents that don't have variation and display an error every time I find one.
For example, when I find "t(é|e)làphone", it displays an error just for the "à". Right now the code only shows the "à" but not the "é" from "télephone" because it overlaps with the condition that I used above: x[-1] == "|".

Any ideas on how can I fix this? Maybe another approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about this regular expression to find the accents that have variations? It checks for any accent that is preceded by either "(" or "|" and that is followed by either ")" or "|". I tested this using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), a great website for learning more about regular expressions.

You can then loop over the string and report any accents that the regex didn't find

```py
import re

accents = ['é', 'à', 'è', 'ù', 'â', 'ê', 'î', 'ô', 'û', 'ç', 'ë', 'ï', 'ü']


def alert_bad_accents(test_str):
    regex = r"(?<=[\(\|])[éàèùâêîôûçëïü](?=[\)\|])"
    matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)
    good_locations = [match.start() for match in matches]
    for i, c in enumerate(test_str):
        if c in accents and i not in good_locations:
            print(f"Error found at column {i}, accent {c} has no variation")


test_strs = ["t(é|e)làphone|télephone|portland(e|é)",
             "t(é|e)laphonë|telephone|üportland(e|é)"]
for test_str in test_strs:
    print(f"Testing {test_str}")
    alert_bad_accents(test_str)
    print()
```

Comment: Can't catch **accent** when being at the beginning or in the end of the word. Like this one
`"t(é|e)laphonë|telephone|üportland(e|é)"`

Comment: Ah great point, I've fixed it to account for your test case!

Comment: You are a genius!! Thank you so much, it totally worked! Too bad I can't give you a feedback, it says that I need 15 reputation points to do so.